# BASH - Regex match line in file.txt with more than one delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Good morning guys!

I'm trying to get my script to read user input, match a keyword in file.txt and return a random delimited response based on that match. I can match the keyword and return ONE response, but I can't wrap my head around how to randomize a number of possible responses.

For example, I have in `file.txt`:

```
big bird|Big birds tend to be big.;;They have wings.
big truck|I love trucks!;;Ford makes nice big trucks. 
red truck|Red is my favorite color.;;Red is also a name.
```

Here's my code which works fine with the first delimiter (|) and returns the ENTIRE response after it.

```
read -p " " query
response="$(awk -F\| -v r="$query" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file.txt)"
echo "$query"
```

So, for example:

> Input: big bird

> Output: Big birds tend to be big.;;They have wings.

But I need to get it to return a RANDOM response delimited on the same line a second time with double semicolons (`;;`).

So, when that input is entered, it should randomly return either "Big birds tend to be big." **or** "They have wings." Not both at the same time.

Any idea how?

Comment: 1. Filter line with `big bird`. 2. Replace `;;` with a newline with `sed`. 3. Pick random line with `shuf`.

Comment: I might think about this differently --  A lot simpler --  I would name a **file** `big bird` --  use the input to grab `big bird` -- open it and grab a random line ( separated by hard break `\r\n` ) and pick a (kind of) random line like so `sort -R input | head -n 1`. --  Acting as a mini database per se --  You could open any file and add/remove lines as you see fit.

Comment: Interesting idea Zak. But this is for a chat script of sorts and there may be thousands of lines in file.txt. It wouldn't be practical to create a file for every expected input. Need to find a way to process this line by line within one large text file. I'm currently looking @KamilCuk's suggestion and trying to find a way of doing that. Man page for sed is confusing as hell but I might figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F\| -v r="$query" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file.txt |
sed 's/;;/\n/g' | shuf -n1
```

Comment: This worked beautifully @KamilCuk. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using *bash* and GNU *sed*:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p " " query
sed -n "/^$query|/s/.*|\(.*\);;\(.*\)/\\$((RANDOM%2 + 1))/p" file.txt
```

Or using *bash* only (no external command used):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p " " query
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == $query\|* ]]; then
        line=${line#*|}
        field[0]=${line%;;*}
        field[1]=${line#*;;}
        echo "${field[RANDOM%2]}"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for an awesome answer. Perfect!