# Partial string match using AWK

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

Good morning guys!

I have the following lines in file.txt:

```
big bird|Big birds tend to be big.;;They have wings.
big truck|I love big trucks!;;Ford makes nice big trucks. 
red truck|Red is my favorite color.;;Red is also a name.
```

My two delimiters are the pipe (|) and the double semicolons (;;). My script takes an input, matches it to a line in file.txt BEFORE the pipe (|) and randomly returns a corresponding output after the pipe delimited by (;;).

```
read -p " " query
response="$(awk -F\| -v r="$query" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file.txt | sed 's/;;/\n/g' | shuf -n1)"
echo "$response"
```

Example:

```
Input: big truck
Output: Ford makes nice big trucks.
```

But this doesn't work unless the input is an exact match. How can I modify the **awk** expression to allow it to accept partial matches or in cases where the two words are inverted? (e.g. "truck big" instead of "big truck"

Desired behavior matching "big" and "truck" and returning a random output from the line:

```
Input: some trucks are big
Output: Ford makes nice big trucks.
```

Many MANY thanks in advance!

Comment: for partial match, you can use `$1 ~ r` (however you have to be careful about ``\`` characters)... matching different combinations of the word will depend whether you need a general solution or if you have fixed number of terms, for example, if it is always one or two words separated by spaces or there can be something like `big green australian sub-urban mammal` or whatever

Comment: What should happen  when input is `big bird truck`, or even `big red bird truck` ?

Comment: @Sundeep 5 or 6 words will be the extent of it. Inputs won't get much bigger than that. Can you please elaborate on how to use $1 ~ r in the codebase above and the \ character you mentioned? Does something need to be escaped for safety and how? Thanks.

Comment: @Luuk That'll happen rarely if not never. In such a case it should return the first matching line. Thank you so much for bringing it up though. An important point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script 'do.awk':

```
BEGIN{
        split(input,s," ");
        for (i in s) s2[s[i]]=i;
        srand();
}
{
        split($1,a," ");
        m=0;
        for(i in a) {
                if (a[i] in s2) then m++;
        }
        # add if words match (m>0), first matchcount, then $2
        if (m>0) {
                r[z++]=m";;"$2
                }
}
END {
        # sort array r, last line will have highest matchcount
        n = asort(r);
        # print last value
        # print r[n];
        # get random piece, but exclude r2[1], because it is matchcount.
        x=split(r[n],r2,";;")-1;
        x = int(rand()*x);
        print  r2[x+2];
}
```

`awk -v input="big red" -F\|  -f do.awk file.txt`
will output "Red is also a name" or "Red is my favorite color"

I replaced the random function, for which you used `shuf`, with the function `rand()` from awk.
(i do hope it's random enough).

EDIT:
i noticed you have another post about the RANDOM stuff here: [BASH - Regex match line in file.txt with more than one delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585317/bash-regex-match-line-in-file-txt-with-more-than-one-delimiter)

EDIT2:
The matchcount can be the same for multiple lines. If this is true we shoul add all the texts, and then pick a random one.

I changed the `END` section as follows:

```
END {
        # sort array r, last line(s) will have highest matchcount
        n = asort(r);
        split(r[n],t,";;");
        m = t[1];
        # add all textx with matchcount=m
        o="";
        for(i=length(r); i>=1; i--) {
                split(r[i],t,";;")
                if(t[1]==m) {
                        for (j=2; j<=length(t); j++) {
                                o=o";;"t[j];
                        }
                } else {
                        break;
                }
        }

        # get random piece, from o.
        x=split(o,r2,";;")-1;
        m=r2[1];
        x = int(rand()*x);
        print  r2[x+2];
}
```

EDIT:
Finally i should  have mentioned that `asort()` is only available in gawk.

Comment: Many thanks @Luuk, very cool approach. It's working beautifully except it seems to be returning any match at random when it's supposed to return the "best match" per se. For example, when I remove bird from the line "big bird" in file.txt and have something like "big|Big is an adjective.;;Big isn't small.", input=big returns from the line with trucks instead of this line where it's a 100% match with no leftover keywords. Any chance I can have you remedy this for a whole lot of heartfelt appreciation?

Comment: The 'matchcount' is the same from more than 1 lines, and currently it is returning a random piece from the last line. I will take a look if i can add this.

Comment: Hi @Luuk, thanks for the fantastic effort but it's still not returning the "best match". When there's a 100% match with no leftover input keywords, that should be prioritized and be the one to be returned. For example when input is just "big", it should return from this line: "big|Big is an adjective.;;Big isn't small.", instead of big truck|I love big trucks!;;Ford makes nice big trucks..... because in the first case it's a 100% word match (only "big") and in the second case it's a 50% word match ("big" and "truck").

Comment: I gave you a thing to get started, you can adapt these things yourself. SO is about learning, you should learn something too 

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want a regexp or string match, nor if if you want a partial match on the whole of $1 or on parts of the "words" in $1 or whole words in $1 or something else. The following will do a whole-word string match on the parts of $1 as that seems to me to be what you're most likely to be asking for. You also didn't say how you want duplicates in the input or in the query string handled so the following matches unique words (as opposed to counting occurrences of words, for example):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p " " query

response="$(
    awk -v query="$query" '
        BEGIN {
            split(query,tmp)
            for (i in tmp) {
                targets[tmp[i]]
            }

            for (word in targets) {
                targetCnt++
            }

            FS = "[|]"
        }
        {
            delete present
            split($1,tmp," ")
            for (i in tmp) {
                present[tmp[i]]
            }

            matchCnt = 0
            for (word in targets) {
                if (word in present) {
                    matchCnt++
                }
            }

            if ( targetCnt == matchCnt ) {
                sub(/.*;;/,"")
                print
            }
        }
    ' file |
    shuf |
    head -1
)"

printf '%s\n' "$response"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
 truck
Red is also a name.
$ ./tst.sh
 truck
Ford makes nice big trucks.
$ ./tst.sh
 truck big
Ford makes nice big trucks.
$ ./tst.sh
 truck big
Ford makes nice big trucks.
```